# Плагин по управлению яркости экрана в Unity на платформе Android

Tags: java, android, c#, unity3d

У меня есть java-код по управлению яркостью экрана, который отлично работает в Android Studio.

Метод привожу в коде ниже. Метод принимает целочисленное значение "value", которое далее устанавливается в качестве яркости.

```
public static int HardwareBrightnessSet (int value) {
    Activity activity = currentActivity;
    Context context = activity.getApplicationContext();
    Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,value);
    return  value;
}
```

В Unity я вызываю метод таким образом:

```
    void SetBrightnessHardware(int value)
{
    var androidPlugin = new AndroidJavaObject("vrcorp.com.brightness.BrightnessControl");
    int _value = androidPlugin.Call<int>("HardwareBrightnessSet",200);        
    _get.text = String.Format("Значение яркости экрана {0}", _value);
}
```

Unity никак не реагирует.
При этом, если в Android Studio я просто получаю данные через "Settings.System.getInt, то всё нормально, значение яркости выводится.

По всей видимости именно при попытке передать и установить данные что-то не получается.

При этом никакой ошибки нет. Просто текст, на который навешан метод, никак не реагирует.

Comment: Попробуйте вместо 'AndroidJavaObject' - 'AndroidJavaClass'  и вместо 'androidPlugin.Call<int>("HardwareBrightnessSet",200)'  - 'androidPlugin.CallStatic<int>("HardwareBrightnessSet",new object[]{200})'